# Can't run crontab django command

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a bash script  `run.sh --- -rwxrwxr-x` (I did chmod +x run.sh)

When i run `./run.sh` script works fine (appended data to the file)

But It did not work in crontab

`crontab -l`  shows  `* * * * * ./run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=eda_parser.settings # eda_parser -- name of the project and the main app
cd /home/alex/root_folder/projects/5_eda_parser/eda_parser
source ../venv/bin/activate # run venv
python manage.py delete_old # main django command
```

---

```
eda_parser/
├── manage.py
├── eda_parser # main app
...
├── run.sh # script to run
├── scraper # django commands app
│   ...
│   ├── management
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── delete_old.py # code of the command
```

Comment: You surely have to provide the entire path to your script in crontab instead of `./run.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. activate your virtual environment
2. type in `which python` to know the path of your python executable and then use this python executable path in your shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=eda_parser.settings # eda_parser -- name of the project and the main app
/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/virtual_environment/bin/python /absolute/path/of/your/manage.py delete_old # main django command
```

also, you need to give the absolute path of your shell script when setting up crontab.
let's suppose you want it to run at `01:15`, append this in `crontab -e`.

```
15 1 * * * /absolute/path/to/your/shell/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!

Solution, that works for me

```
* * * * * /home/alex/root_folder/projects/5_eda_parser/eda_parser/run.sh
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=eda_parser.settings
cd /home/alex/root_folder/projects/5_eda_parser/eda_parser
source ../venv/bin/activate
python manage.py delete_old
```